# linking a function to a clicking event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

Im trying to code a functionality so when I click on a certain location button that markers info window pops up. Ive got the code to console log the certain title and location of the marker, but when i try to call the infowindow in the viewmodel it comes up undefined. I know that the Infowindow  is in the init function for google map, i cant seem to figure out how to open it from the viewmodel[image]

and here is my code for the view model:

```
   function viewModel() {
      this.marker = locationArray().location;
      this.openWindow = function(location){
      if(this.marker){
        console.log(this.marker);

      };
    }
}
```

and my click event:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker){
          return function() {
          viewModel()
           infoWindow.setContent("<div>" + marker.title + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open( map, marker);
       }  
      })(marker));
```

here is my google map api, hopefully this will help :

```
         function initMap() {


         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 41.764117, lng: -72.676470},
            zoom: 13,
            styles: style
         });

// Iterates through the locationArray and gives the marker a proper
// location.
             for(var i = 0; i < locationArray().length; i++){
                var locations = locationArray()[i].location;
                var title = locationArray()[i].title;

               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: locations,
                   map: map,
                   title: title,
                   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });

           locationArray()[i].marker = marker;

           var message = "hello world!";

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: title,
              position: locations
           });


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker){
          return function() {
          viewModel();
          infoWindow.setContent("<div>" + marker.title + "</div>");
          infoWindow.open( map, marker);
      }
    })(marker));


           };

          };
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would cause your issue, but you don't have a semicolon after your call to viewModel() in your event listener. Also, when you call viewModel(), shouldn't you pass this to it? Or does it automatically inherit this from the event?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle for the same?

Comment: I have my git hub repo if that helps. https://github.com/Jcook894/FEND_Neighborhood_Project

Answer (score 1):

You definition of `marker` in the `ViewModel` is ambiguous. You should in general define the observables inside the `ViewModel`.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.locations = ko.observableArray(data.locations || []);
    self.showMarker(function(loc) {          // bind this to click (in html)
        loc.marker.showInfo();        // I'm not sure if loc.marker.click() would work
    });
}
var locations = [];       // your list of locations
ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel({locations: locations}) );
```

And you can bind the click event of your marker in a simpler way, that'll also help to easily call the

```
marker.showInfo = function() {
    infoWindow.setContent("<div>" + this.title + "</div>");
    infoWindow.open( map, this);
};
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', marker.showInfo);
```